# c - Array of pointer to functions, having different number of arguments

Tags: pointers, function-pointers, arduino-ide

I am making a simple scheduler that executes functions contained in a FIFO queue.

Those functions have a same return type `int`, but have different number of `int` arguments.

I tried to implement it [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043953/how-to-define-an-array-of-function-pointers-and-the-functions-dont-have-same-in), but it does not seem to work. The compiler forbids conversion between `int(*)()` , `int(*)(int)`, `int(*)(int, int)`, or to any of those sort. (Arduino Sketch compiler)

Is there a way to solve this problem, or could you recommend a better way around? Thanks!

My code:

```
typedef int (*fnptr)(); // Tried this!

int foo(int var) {
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    fnptr fp = &foo; // error: invalid conversion from 
                     // 'int (*)(int)' to 'int (*)()' 
                     // [-fpermissive]
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try `fnptr fp = foo;`?

Comment: Also, please be aware, using a mismatched function pointer to call a function can invoke UB.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Yup, it throws the same error.  'fnptr fp = &foo()' also makes the same error.

Comment: I believe [your code works in C89](http://ideone.com/r9PDEe). C99 introduced the "limitation" of ["remove implicit int"](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#Forewordp5).

Comment: @upoque i did not add the `()`

Comment: @SouravGhosh Yes, I tried both 'fnptr fp = foo;' and 'fnptr fp = &foo();'.

Comment: @pmg I have a doubt, will using a function pointer to function with varying number of arguments like [here](http://www.lemoda.net/c/function-pointer-ellipsis/) help?

Comment: @jblixr: for some specific functionality that could work -- [example at codepad](http://codepad.org/p7yUp9LU)

Answer (score 0):

You can cast:

```
fnptr fp = reinterpret_cast<fnptr>(foo);
```

The `()`s are the "function call operator", adding them makes no sense at all in this situation, it changes the expression from "take the address of this function" to "take the address of this function's return value".

Note that aboev I don't even include the `&`, this is because the name of a function acts pretty much like a function pointer so it's already an address.